# Regular expression for a complex string

Tags: java, regex

I am new to regexp. I need to validate a string, but when I use my current attempt it is always returning false.

Rules:

1. A text matcher like "polygon(( ))"
2. number matcher like X Y, where x and y can be any double numbers
3. as many X Y pairs, separated by comma.

eg:

```
PolyGoN((
-74.0075783459999 40.710775696, 
-74.007375926 40.710655064, 
-74.0074640719999 40.7108592490001, 
-74.0075783459999 40.710775696))
```

Here is the code that I used:

```
String inputString = "POLYGON((-74.0075783459999 40.710775696, -74.007375926 40.710655064, -74.0072836009999 40.710720973, -74.0075783459999 40.710775696))";
String regexp = "polygon[\\((][(\\-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?)\\s*(\\-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?)]*[\\))]";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regexp, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputString);
boolean result = matcher.matches();
```

Comment: You don't seem to understand the meaning of a character class.

Comment: Are new lines present in your actual input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
m|Polygon\(\(((\s*-?\d+\.\d+\s*){2},)*(\s*-?\d+\.\d+\s*){2}\)\)|i
```

Comment: This also works and more simple, Thanks! But I didn't understand the letters m and i at start and end of the expression.What does that signify?

Comment: in some langauges m means match and the i is a flag to set the case insenstive. I think in java you define it as a match by which function you use (as opposed to a replace) and pass the flags in a special method, but i just type it out in the form im most familiar with (perl)... Feel free to adjust as need to make it java.

Comment: I need to extract the set of repeating numbers in "X Y" format(as a string array). And I am using Pattern.compile("\\s*((\\s*-?\\d+\\.\\d+\\s*){2})") and a matcher with the same input string as above. iterating through a loop and getting these numbers with Matcher.group(1). Is there any simple way to get them as a string array?

Answer (score 3):

`[\\((]` is incorrect way of specifying that you need `(` twice. No matter how many times you repeat a character but inside a character class `[]` it counts only once. Since, it's the same character repeating you don't even need a character class there but just the character `\\(` with a quantifier that tells how many times it should repeat `{2}`. So, you need `\\({2}` at the start and `\\){2}` at the end.

Another problem with your use of `[]` is that you used them to denote a group of double pairs that repeats (using `*`). You always use `()` for grouping a part of your match. `[]` denotes a character class only. I wonder why you got that wrong because you grouped your doubles and their pairs correctly.

Next, you've forgotten to match all the commas `,` separating the double pairs. I've included that as `(,\\s*)?` in my regex. The hyphen `-` (or the negative sign here) doesn't need to be escaped since it's not inside a character class `[]` and so the regex parser knows you're not using it to specify a character range.

The corrected regex is *(indented for clarity)*

```
polygon\({2}\s*(
    (-?\d+(\.\d+)?)\s*(-?\d+(\.\d+)?)(,\s*)
  )*(-?\d+(\.\d+)?)\s*(-?\d+(\.\d+)?)
\s*\){2}
```

Comment: Awesome explanation Ravi. I tried this and it got working. This is the first time am using this site and was happy about it. Thank you so much.